# Binarization for large directional gradient grayscale image

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I am trying to binarize grayscale images with large gradients in one direction.

Apparently, normal methods including `Otsu`'s are not good enough to do this job.

I tried to use `Sobel` gradients and the `Bradley adaptive thresholding`, by which I get OK results, but there are some issues as indicated in the attached picture.

From the section gradient curve, we could see the gradient difference is very big at the beginning, so I split the `Sobel` result and do the `adaptive thresholding` separately, and then fuse the two results together.

##### My question is:

Are there any other better methods to do this job? To better understand what I do, I post my sample python code here. Thanks for your attention.

```py
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

def bradley_threshold(inputMat,ddepth):
    nRows = inputMat.shape[0]
    nCols = inputMat.shape[1]
    sumMat = cv.integral(inputMat, ddepth)

    S = max(nRows, nCols) / 8
    T = 0.15
    s2 = int(S / 2)
    outputMat = np.zeros(inputMat.shape, np.uint8)
    for i in range(nRows):
        y1 = i - s2
        y2 = i + s2
        if y1 < 0:
            y1 = 0
        if y2 >= nRows:
            y2 = nRows - 1
        y1+=1
        y2+=1

        for j in range(nCols):
            # set the SxS region
            x1 = j - s2
            x2 = j + s2
            if x1 < 0:
                x1 = 0
            if x2 >= nCols:
                x2 = nCols - 1;

            x1 += 1
            x2 += 1
            count = (x2 - x1) * (y2 - y1)
            sum = sumMat[y2, x2]-sumMat[y1, x2]-sumMat[y2, x1]+sumMat[y1, x1]
            if inputMat[i, j] * count <= sum * (1.0 - T):
                outputMat[i, j] = 0
            else:
                outputMat[i, j] = 255
    return outputMat

if __name__ == '__main__':
    gray = cv.imread('sample.png', cv.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
    image = cv.cvtColor(gray,cv.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
    blur = cv.medianBlur(gray, 3)
    sobel = cv.Sobel(gray, cv.CV_32F, 1, 0, 1);
    inverse = -sobel;
    inverse[inverse < 0] = 0
    thresh = bradley_threshold(inverse, cv.CV_32F)

    splitter = 31
    part1 = inverse[:,:31]
    part2 = inverse[:,31:]
    thresh1 = bradley_threshold(part1, cv.CV_32F)
    thresh2 = bradley_threshold(part2, cv.CV_32F)
    thresh_part = np.concatenate((thresh1, thresh2), axis=1)
    cv.imwrite('bad_binary.png',thresh)
    cv.imwrite('good_binary.png',thresh_part)
    plt.imshow(thresh, cmap='gray')
    plt.show()
    plt.imshow(thresh_part, cmap='gray')
    plt.show()
    plt.plot(inverse[inverse.shape[0]-1, :])
    plt.show()
```

[image: input image]

[image: bad result]

[image: good result]

[image: section gradient curve]

Comment: What is your goal?

Comment: we need a tag for "xray inspection of lithium ion batteries". if they do the same thing everyone else does with these pictures, they want to count the number of layers in the coil. such questions have been asked maybe a handful of times already.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I agree. This is a different battery from the one I asked before. Second order gradient doesn't work well for this one, so I used one order, but facing the binarization problem to separate anodes and cathodes, especially for the first a few layers.

Comment: @CrisLuengo To separate stripes (anode and cathode of lithium battery).